# How to load data from another table/model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Having just started with Cake, I'm now very frustrated having already spent several hours reading examples etc What I want to do seems so simple, but I can't make enough sense of the documentation to find out how to do this. It's very simple:

I have 2 tables:

- items
- categories (eg books, cd)

New items will be created constantly, each has a category.

All I want to do is create a dropdown filter in the items list view. But to do this I need to load the list of categories.

So the basic problem is, how do I access the categories table from the items table?

Answer (score 2):

Finally a solution.

In the items controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Categories');

$categories = $this->Categories->find()->all();
```

Or to remove all the cake crud from the returned object:

```
 $categories = $this->Categories->find("list", array("fields"=>array("Categories.title")))->all();
```

Comment: Assuming that Categories and Items are related, you should be able to skip the `loadModel` call, and use `$this->Items->Categories` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to relate them properly and access the data. I spent a lot of time trying to figure that out before I found the loadModel method. If you could point me in the right direction I'd be very appreciative.

Also, I'm rather puzzled that I'm finding it so hard to find answers to my problems with Cake as examples and tutorials seem scarce. I chose it because it's supposed to be easy and quick, but even as an experienced programmer, so far I'm finding it anything but. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you looking at the official Cake docs? They are pretty comprehensive and easy to understand, at least for this basic stuff. The section you want is [Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html).